# Compression of RGB-D video from a Kinect camera

Tags: video, compression, kinect, image-compression, run-length-encoding

I need to send video from a Kinect camera through a network. I'm capturing video from the following two Kinect sources:

1. 2D color video (**RGB**). 32 bits per pixel. 640x480 at 30fps.
2. Depth data (**D**). 16 bits per pixel representing distance to the closest object in mm. 640x480 at 30fps.

This amounts to a bandwidth of at least roughly 53 MB/s.
That is why I need to encode (compress) both video sources at origin and then decode at target. The RGB-D data will be processed by an object tracking algorithm at target.

So far I've found many papers discussing algorithms to achieve this task, like, for instance, this one: 
[RGB and depth intra-frame Cross-Compression for low bandwidth 3D video](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6460293)

The problem is that the algorithms described in such papers do not have a public access implementation. I know, I could implement them myself, but they make use of many other complex image processing algorithms I do not have a sufficient knowledge about (edge detection, contour characterization, ...).

I actually also found some C++ libraries based on the use of a Discrete median filter, delta (avoid sending redundant data), and LZ4 compression:
[http://thebytekitchen.com/2014/03/24/data-compression-for-the-kinect/](https://thebytekitchen.com/2014/03/24/data-compression-for-the-kinect/)

**My question is:** is there a simpler and/or more efficient way of compressing RGB-D data from a Kinect source?

**PS:** I'm coding in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a recent search on the problem I found a paper that describes compressing depth images using the h264 video codec. The authors also provide basic software:

- Paper: http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~stachnis/pdf/nenci14iros.pdf
- Software: http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/data-software/depth-streaming-using-h-264/

A problem is that h264 can introduce compression artifacts. To minimize the errors introduced by the codec the depth image is split into multiple channels which represent different ranges of distances.